# Can 'truck' be used as a verb?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, grammaticality, verbs

I am trying to use *truck* as a verb. Is this acceptable?

> I will truck no such thought.

Comment: What did your dictionary tell you?

Comment: looked at 3 diff dictionaries. only mention i saw was: truck used in dealing with people: 'I'll have no truck with him.'

Comment: And what was the definition given for the *truck* in that example? And was the entry marked as a verb? And did you look in all your 3 dictionaries for truck-entries marked as verbs? Don’t take me the wrong way, I am not trying to be a jerk to you, but I am trying to get you to read your dictionaries more closely, with more attention, because I know for a fact the answer you want is in there.

Comment: 'I will have no truck with unresearched questions' still uses 'truck' as a noun.

Comment: Apparently, "The Doo-dah man" does it all the time...

Answer (score 2):

## Don’t confuse *truck no* with *brook no*

I don’t know why you are trying to use *truck* as a verb, but no, that’s probably not going to be widely understood. It looks like you are using *truck* when you meant to say *brook*:

- I will brook no such thought.

Where here *brook* is an old verb that the OED says this about:

> To put up with, bear with, endure, tolerate [a fig. sense of ‘to stomach’ in 2]. Now only in negative or preclusive constructions.

In contrast, there’s an old meaning of *truck* that as a noun means “dealings” and as a verb means “to have dealings with”, and which like *brook* is also now mainly used in negative contexts.

For the noun *truck* the OED provides this now somewhat rarefied sense:

> ‘Traffic’, intercourse, communication, dealings. Now usually in negative contexts: ***to have no truck with*** (a person or thing), etc.

For the verb *truck* with a related meaning to that of the noun just given, they give this sense:

> *intr*. *fig*. or in fig. context: To bargain or deal for a commodity, *with* a person; to negotiate; also to have dealings *in*, to trade; esp. of dealings of an underhand or improper character: to traffic.

The most recent citation for that sense of the verb is:

> **1904**   *Daily News* 7 Dec. 11 —  Private communities have no business to ‘truck with’ the State.

Which I note is again in a negative context.

The most common sense of the verb *truck* in present-day English is the one involving trucks or trucking (lorries). One OED citation is:

> **1982**   L. Kallen *Introd. C. B. Greenfield* iv. 47  — The produce, trucked in daily from their own upstate farm, was fresh.

There’s also the kind of *truck* verb that appears in the slang phrase “to keep on trucking”, but that’s not what you mean here.

Comment: I knew 'truck no' was wrong but there was a wisp of a shadow left on my mind regarding something - _something_ - else. 'Brook' was what I could not remember.

Comment: Having read this, I am left with the feeling that there is actually very little difference between "truck no" and "brook no".

Answer (score 0):

According to Wikipedia, "Keep on truckin" is a song created by Eddie Kendricks in 1973. While not the most credible, I will use wiki to show how "truckin'" is properly used. The lyrics go: 
**In old Temptations' rain, I'm duckin'
For your love through sleet or snow, I'm truckin'**.
This sort of makes sense as you have to drive through the weather in a truck. Which gives rise to the expressions of "I have to keep on truckin" like if you are having a hard day which is kind of like slang. I don't think it works in your sentence. Why not use a more common word like **"have"** as in: **"I will have no such thoughts".** That sounds much better.

Comment: my research has improved: it can be a verb:  (transitive, slang) To fight or otherwise physically engage with. quotations ▲

    1993, Sue Grafton, "J" Is for Judgment

        Both deputies were big, made of dense flesh and tough experience. . . . I wouldn't have wanted to truck with either one of them.

Comment: I wouldn't have wanted to truck with either one of them ... sounds perfect.